# Good public API for use in demos and documentation?

Tags: api

I have created a utility library and open sourced it on Github, and I'd like to document the HTTP utilities.  I created this around some apps I've developed, but none of the APIs I use are for public consumption.  I want to use a well known public API in my documentation so that code samples will work and be really easy to understand for the user, but I don't work with any such API so I'm not familiar with any...looking for suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand your use of the term API. Are you looking for a documentation generator? If so, for which language?

Comment: @ajlane No, I mean a web product that offers a public api.  For example, Twitter, but I personally am not into Twitter, so I'd rather not represent my library with examples of how to pull data from Twitter.  I developed a client side library for consuming web resources, and the most common case is data from an api.  To be more clear, the platform I created this library for is Android.  Android apps typically consume raw data, so my HTTP utilities make this a one line operation (or a few if passing extra objects like cookies, POST params, auth creds, etc).

Comment: You can try Faroo.com - free web search API open for anybody: http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmable Web has a list of popular public web APIs sorted by the number of mashups which use it: http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?sort=mashups

The top 10 from that list:

1. Google Maps
2. Twitter
3. YouTube
4. Flickr
5. Amazon
6. Facebook
7. Twilio
8. Last.fm
9. eBay
10. Google Search